# Yii2: Attribute (CLIENT_ID) is invalid

Tags: php, yii2

I'm trying to save a field from another table in update action. Here is my update action.

```
public function actionUpdateResumo($id)
{
    $model = $this->findModel($id);
    $model->situacao = $model->nginAgentDetail->situacao;

    if ($model->load(Yii::$app->request->post()) && $model->validate()) {

        $nginAgentDet = NginAgentDetail::find()
        ->where(['CLIENT_ID'=>$id])->one();

        $nginAgentDet->situacao = Yii::$app->request->post()['EtuLoja']['situacao'];

        if ($model->save() && $nginAgentDet->save()) {

            return $this->redirect(['view', 'id' => $model->ID]);
        } else {
            var_dump($nginAgentDet->getErrors());die;
        }
    } else {
        return $this->render('update-resumo', [
            'model' => $model,
        ]);
    }
}
```

When i click update it displays the message:

> Client  ID is invalid.

Client ID is a field from the other table (NginAgentDetail)

In my model i have this relation:

```
public function getNginAgentDetail()
{
    return $this->hasOne(NginAgentDetail::className(),['CLIENT_ID' => 'ID']);        
}
```

and in the other table i have this relation:

```
public function getEtuLojas()
{
    return $this->hasMany(EtuLoja::className(), ['ID' => 'CLIENT_ID']);
}
```

NginAgentDetail model:

```
    class NginAgentDetail extends \yii\db\ActiveRecord
{

public static function tableName()
{
    return 'ngin_agent_detail';
}

public function rules()
{
    return [
        [['situacao'], 'string'],
        // [['valMoeda'], 'number'],
        [['CLIENT_ID'], 'integer'],
        [['OPERATION_DATE', 'CATEGORY', 'MOV_TYPE', 'VALUE', 'COMMISSION', 'AFTER_BALANCE', 'ORIGIN_DESTINY', 'VALUES', 'USER'], 'string', 'max' => 100],
        [['CLIENT_ID'], 'exist', 'skipOnError' => true, 'targetClass' => MasterLoja::className(), 'targetAttribute' => ['CLIENT_ID' => 'id']],
    ];
}

public function attributeLabels()
{
    return [
        'id_pk' => 'Id Pk',
        'OPERATION_DATE' => 'Operation  Date',
        'CLIENT_ID' => 'Client  ID',
        'CATEGORY' => 'Category',
        'MOV_TYPE' => 'Mov  Type',
        'VALUE' => 'Value',
        'COMMISSION' => 'Commission',
        'AFTER_BALANCE' => 'After  Balance',
        'ORIGIN_DESTINY' => 'Origin  Destiny',
        'VALUES' => 'Values',
        'USER' => 'User',
        'situacao' => 'Status',
    ];
}

public function getEtuLojas()
{
    return $this->hasMany(EtuLoja::className(), ['ID' => 'CLIENT_ID']);
}

public function getMasterLoja()
{
    return $this->hasMany(MasterLoja::className(), ['id' => 'ORIGIN_DESTINY']);
}

}
```

FindModel function:

```
protected function findModel($id)
{
    if (($model = EtuLoja::findOne($id)) !== null) {
        return $model;
    }

    throw new NotFoundHttpException('The requested page does not exist.');
}
```

**EDIT**

I found what was causing te invalid Client ID message. It was this validation rule in **NginAgentDetail** model:

```
[['CLIENT_ID'], 'exist', 'skipOnError' => true, 'targetClass' => MasterLoja::className(), 'targetAttribute' => ['CLIENT_ID' => 'id']],
```

The problem now is that it appears to be saving to the database but when i return to the gridview the attribute situacao stays the same, i mean it doesn't update.

Comment: add your model `NginAgentDetail`

Comment: @MuhammadOmerAslam added.

Comment: can you confirm if the error is not on the line `$model->situacao = $model->nginAgentDetail->situacao;` ?

Comment: and which model are you returning from this function `$this->findModel($id);`

Comment: @MuhammadOmerAslam i think the error is not on that line, but i'm not sure. That line is to get the field value to display on the form when i click update. Also i added the findModel function. It returns the model that's the controller is from. I can show you my code in skype if you want. or Team viewer.

Comment: is `situacao` a custom attribute in the model `EtuLoja` ?

Comment: @MuhammadOmerAslam Yii (Yes It Is).

Comment: Add the complete error message.